# Change Crystal Reports Group Header Field at Run Time

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports 2008 report that has fields e.g Sector,Branch, Department and a bunch of other fields.The requirement is that the same report should be able to allow grouping by Sector,Branch or Department.I'm trying to avoid creating the same report 3 times with the only difference being the Group Header field.My question is if there is a way to dynamically change the group header at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Make the header a formula, then set the formula to one of these fields at runtime.  I consolidated a hundred or so different reports into about a dozen RPT files years ago using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

How to Pass Crystal Repor Header Information from any asp.net form button click its possible then how it possible

Answer (score 0):

visit this msdn link:

```
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288421(VS.71).aspx#
```